# tree (sequence) diagram in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I want to draw tree diagram with Asymptote. But have some problems.

I searched and found 2 hints on the web.
http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/FAQ/section4.html
http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Frames-and-pictures.html

Using theese tips, and tried to *box* and *trees*.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(5cm);

usepackage(amsmath);

frame f1;
label(f1, "$\mathbb{N} \models A(0)$", Draw);
add(f1, (0, 5))

frame f2;
label(f2, "$\mathbb{N} \models A(1)$", Draw);
add(f2, (0, 4));

draw(f1 -- f2);
```

But this doesn't work. Last *draw(f1 -- f2);* command is wrong.

*draw* commands need coordinate. But this method is... not smart (for me).

I want to **connect** 2 boxes. How Can I connect 2 objects?

I found *drawtree* module in the official tutorials PDF, but it looks difficult to use flexibly(is tree's shape changeable?).

If there is a way of easily using *drawtree* module, would you tell that?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I find the graph theory module good for this kind of thing.  Documentation could be better, but the functionality works for me.  https://github.com/taoari/asy-graphtheory

Comment: Links are good!

Answer (score 2):

The following code works as a standalone `asymptote` script.  I haven't used the `drawtree` module so I can't help you with that.  In my code, I am not using frames.  Instead, each label is drawn in the default picture.

```
texpreamble("\usepackage{amssymb}");
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(5cm);

pair p1 = (0, 5);
pair p2 = (0, 4);

draw(p1--p2);

label("$\mathbb{N} \models A(0)$", p1, FillDraw(white, black));
label("$\mathbb{N} \models A(1)$", p2, FillDraw(white, black));
```

[image]

Comment: Your method is simple and useful! Thank you!But I have an another problem.

Comment: When I change _draw(p1--p2)_ to _draw(p1--p2, arrow=Arrow)_, arrow is not displayed. If the second label is not present, the arrow can be seen. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @kogemochi: The line extends to the middle of the label, so the arrow head is filled over when the label is drawn.  The easiest solution might be to use MidArrow instead.

Comment: Getting your hint, searched further, _draw(p1--p2, arrow=Arrow(position=0.945))_ was found. It looks nice for me. Options are difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Since alternative methodologies are generally acceptable, I cannot resist providing a **forest** solution.

`math content` puts the content of all nodes in maths mode, avoiding the need for `$...$`. `draw` draws a border around each node in the tree.

The nodes are automatically connected: parent to child for each parent-child relationship. (Use `<node content>, no edge` for exceptions.) I've specified `l sep` to match the `unit` defined in the original code. This is the minimum distance between levels of the tree. (5cm is a lot.)

**forest** does not need explicit coordinates. It will automatically format the tree.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    math content,
    l sep=50mm,
  }
  [\mathbb{N} \models A(0)
    [\mathbb{N} \models A(1)]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: alternative solution]

To alter the appearance of the tree is very easy. You just alter the preamble of the `forest` environment.

For example,

```
   for tree={
    draw=red,
    thick,
    edge={blue, thick, <->},
    fill=red!10,
    math content,
    l sep=50mm,
    grow=45,
  }
```

produces

[image: altered tree]

while the specification for the tree itself remains identical

```
  [\mathbb{N} \models A(0)
    [\mathbb{N} \models A(1)]
  ]
```

Comment: I didn't know well about tikz. Thank you.